# Explaining perl split with backslash in string pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, perl, split

I'm the author of [pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer), perl to python converter, and I'm trying to translate a perl split statement that has a string pattern that includes a backslash, and I need some help understanding the behavior.  Here is the example based on the source code I'm trying to translate:

```
$s = 'a|b|c';
@a = split '\|', $s;
print scalar(@a) . "\n";
print "@a\n";
```

The output is:

```
3
a b c
```

Now if I just print `'\|'` it prints `\|` so I'm not sure why the backslash is being ignored in the string pattern.  The documentation doesn't say much of anything about a string being used as a pattern, except for the `' '` special case.  Feeding `'\|'` to python string split will not split this string.

Even more strange is what happens if I change the above code to use a double-quoted string:

```
@a = split "\|", $s;
```

Then the output is:

```
5
a | b | c
```

If I change it to a regex, then it does the same thing as if it was a single-quoted string (splitting into 3 pieces), which makes perfect sense because `|` is a special char in a regex so it needs to be escaped:

```
@a = split /\|/, $s;
```

So my question is - how is a split on a string that contains a backslash (in single and then double quotes) supposed to work so I can reproduce it in python?  Should I just remove all backslashes, except for `\\` from a single-quoted input string if it's on a split?

Also, why does a split on `"\|"` (or `"|"`) split the string into 5 pieces?  (I'm thinking of punting on this case.)

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Python?

Comment: I'm generating python code from perl input, for example s.split('|') splits s into 3 pieces but s.split('\|') doesn't split it at all, and certainly nothing I can think of will split it into 5 pieces!

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/issues/138

Comment: I'm thinking the pattern is always being treated as a regex even if it's a simple string, and in the "\|" case, the \ is being removed leaving the pattern as "|" which operates as an empty pattern.

Comment: Just reproduced the split into 5 case: >>> import perllib
>>> perllib.split('|', 'a|b|c')
['a', '|', 'b', '|', 'c']

Answer (score 3):

There's a few interleaved questions so let me go step by step

- Perl's [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) takes a regular expression pattern to identify separators by which it splits the string, in its first argument.  This is a "normal" regex, compiled and ran by the regex engine, but in doing so it does have special cases
- As for delimiters in `split`'s regex: variables in patterns are interpolated except under single quotes, like in regex, what has no relevance for examples here. The string `\|` is pattern `\|` either way, so the literal `|` (and not alternation)

  But for double quotes there is a difference: in `split` the string under the double quotes is first interpolated, apparently including escapes, and only then is the result handed to the regex engine to compile it into a pattern.  So that `"\|"` becomes the pattern `|` for the regex, so yes the alternation! (Not the behavior in regex outside of `split`.)
- What brings us to the issue of `split`-ing with the pattern of `|`, as `split "\|"` or as `split /|/` — that works like splitting with an empty string, a `split`'s specialty  which returns all characters. A regex doesn't behave that way, with `/|/` nor with `//`.

  This behavior of `split` appears undocumented. I can see a rationale like "*split by **either** empty string **or** by empty string -- well, so split by empty string*", what for `split` perhaps makes some sense.

  In regex that doesn't make much sense: Matching "*empty string -or- empty string*" matches the first empty string, what merely succeeds -- but an actual pattern of an empty string has very [distinct behavior](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), which I don't see with `/|/`. (And which is unrelated to what `split` does.) So having a lone `/|/` — a legal pattern — is only confusing as it does nothing.

As for what to do with this for Python, the [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) mentioned by OP in a comment doesn't use regex at all.  To reproduce Perl's `split` operation one needs to use [split from re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split), `re.split(pattern, string,...)`. Then go through details and test behavior in `re` with escaped regex patterns.

Comment: _A regex doesn't behave that way, with /|/ nor with //_  Both compile to a NOTHING node in a regex, so nothing special apparently: `perl -E ' use re "debug";say "abc" =~/|/'`

Comment: Thanks - I now check if the pattern contains any regex chars and use re.split (actually perllib.split) if it does.  If it's just plain chars, then I use str.split.

Comment: @snoopyjc Welcome -- as for "_if the pattern contains any regex chars_" -- it's always a regex even if the pattern is just a string literal.  MIght just always pass it to `re.split`...?

Comment: @clamp Thanks for a comment, good point to look at it with `re`.  I didn't want to expand this answer even more. I got all of `1`, empty lines, and empty string, printed for various uses of either of these two in a normal regex. I'd say that it shouldn't really compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

Perl treats a single quote as-is.  It interpolates double-quotes.

Split expects regex, so the `'\|'` is being treated as regex `\|`, where the `\` is a regex escape char, meaning the `|` is the split char matched.  Perl interpolates the `"\|"` to just `|`, which is regex for OR.

Comment: "_interpolates the "\|" to just |, which is regex for OR_" ... and? Why does that split the string into characters? That is the behavior of an empty pattern -- why does it work that way?  (A normal regex doesn't, `$s =~ /|/` doesn't do that.)  That's the question...

Comment: But /|/ is equivalent to the empty pattern - the first alternation is the empty pattern, which always succeeds, so the second alternation (also the empty pattern is never tried)

Comment: Sorry, didn't expand on the second part ... the OR.  A standalone ```|``` will match between the chars, meaning each char will be a piece as a result of splitting there.